# creating multiple txt files and directories from csv column and have the txt files filled with specific text

Tags: c#, excel, powershell

I have an excel file containing MANY names column and many links column, i need to create directories and text files inside them based on the excel column *. text files filled with same text inside them

Lets say i have an excel file containing column:banana,apple

The output would be Banana directory,apple directory.
Inside apple directory apple.text,inside banana directory a file called banana.text.

Inside the text files banana.text and apple.text i would like to have the same specific text WITH the links as variable inside banana.txt the same text with the apropriate link to banana in the paralel link's column and for apple.text same specific text with the appropriate link to apple in the apple link's column pls .

lets saythe text inside apple.text will looks like:

hello and nice to meet u http://apple.com

lets saythe text inside banana.text will looks like:
hello and nice to meet u http://banana.com

same words in each file just the link will be changing.

I EDITED THE QUESTION.

Comment: This question is off-topic for so many reasons. It's unclear, too broad, no work done, multiple tags... Please read the help section.

Comment: It's a pity SO only allows 5 tags, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think there steps needs for you.

1. first, automated Exccel. 
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c--net
2. find URLs.
   There is many ways for that. I recommended using Regular Expression.
3. find Keyword.
   in URL, remove http protocal related keywords.